# rem font-size not rendering properly in css animation

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-animations, font-size

So I'm trying to have a sentence where certain words are animated (rotated through) - I thought it was working, but once I viewed the site on my mobile I found an issue.
When viewed on a desktop (and even inside dev tools), the animated text is rendered in the correct size. However, once I view it on a mobile device (iPhone), the text becomes super small

I'm also using bootstrap on the page so I thought that maybe something was being overridden. But as you can see I've basically removed all the bootstrap classes and it still isn't working.

```css
.animated span {
  color: #007bff;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-animation: topToBottom 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: topToBottom 10s infinite;
  animation: topToBottom 10s infinite;
}

.animated span:nth-child(2) {
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.animated span:nth-child(3) {
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.animated span:nth-child(4) {
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.animated span:nth-child(5) {
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes topToBottom {

  0%,
  20% {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  /* visible for 1s */
  20.01%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0rem;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class=" cover-heading animated">TribePulse replaces <br />
 <span>status updates</span>
 <span>engagement surveys</span>
 <span>progress reports</span>
 <span>status meetings</span>
 <span>EoD emails</span>
</h1>
```

Demo on glitch: https://empty-cemetery.glitch.me/
When you view it on desktop, all the blue writing is the correct size. However, once you view it on mobile the animated text becomes tiny.

Comment: I checked on my phone, my tablet, a resolution changer, chrome, firefox and another phone. They are all the same size, there is no change in the animated text. I think there is an issue with your phone, maybe.

Comment: Strange... I've tried different browsers on my phone too, but the issue still persists

Answer (score -1):

you can check  how your page looks and performs on a mobile device:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

you can also customize the contents using media queries.Media Queries for Standard Devices

If you want to know more info you can visit:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Yup, so when I was building the webpage I was using that and everything was working. But once I deployed and actually viewed the webpage on a mobile device, the issue became apparent.

Comment: if rem is not working,its better that you can try em.Refer this site: https://css-tricks.com/rem-global-em-local/